# NTFS stream H:stream

Tags: winapi, ntfs

Why I try to open NTFS stream named "file:stream" using CreateFile() - that's OK.

But when file is "H" and I got flash card reader on drive H:, CreateFile() tries to open file named "stream" on flash card, because argument passed to CreateFile() is "H:stream"!

How these named streams should be opened correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this oddball case, you can simply prepend `.\` in front of file name or use full file path. For example, this works for me as expected:

```
.\H:stream
```